# LaTeXにてBibTeXデータベースからの\citeが上手く機能しない

Tags: latex

タイトルの通り、BibTeXデータベースに対する`\cite`が上手くいきません。

下記に使用ファイルを記します。
これが`main.tex`（PDFにするメインのtexファイル）となっています。本文はコマンド以外は省略しています。

```latex
\documentclass[Japanese]{dicomopapers}
%\documentclass[Japanese,noauthor]{dicomopapers}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\def\Underline{\setbox0\hbox\bgroup\let\\\endUnderline}
\def\endUnderline{\vphantom{y}\egroup\smash{\underline{\box0}}\\}
\def\|{\verb|} %|

%概要投稿用余白調整ここから
\setlength{\Jauthorjreceivesep}{0.0mm}
\setlength{\Jreceivejabstsep}{0.0mm}
\setlength{\Jabstsepjkeyword}{0.0mm}
\setlength{\Jkeywordetitle}{0.0mm}
%概要投稿用余白調整ここまで

\begin{document}

% 和文表題
\title{自動運転}

% 英文表題
\etitle{Path Planning}

% 所属ラベルの定義
\affiliate{TODAI}{あ}
　
\author{ほ}{ほ}{TODAI}
\author{あ}{あ}{TODAI}

% 表題などの出力
\maketitle

% 本文はここから始まる
\section{概要}
~\cite{pathfind}


\bibliographystyle{junsrt}
\bibliography{hoge}

\end{document}
```

BibTeXデータベースは下のような内容です。

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{4276103,
  author={P. {Bhattacharya} and M. L. {Gavrilova}},
  booktitle={4th International Symposium on Voronoi Diagrams in Science and Engineering (ISVD 2007)}, 
  title={Voronoi diagram in optimal path planning}, 
  year={2007},
  volume={},
  number={},
  pages={38-47},
  doi={10.1109/ISVD.2007.43}
 }
  
@article{pathfind,
author = {Gasparetto, Alessandro and Boscariol, Paolo and Lanzutti, Albano and Vidoni, Renato},
year = {2015},
month = {03},
pages = {3-27},
title = {Path Planning and Trajectory Planning Algorithms: A General Overview},
volume = {29},
isbn = {978-3-319-14704-8},
journal = {Mechanisms and Machine Science},
doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-14705-5_1}
}

@inproceedings{
  KyTea,
  title={Pointwise prediction for robust, adaptable Japanese morphological analysis},
  author={Neubig, Graham and Nakata, Yosuke and Mori, Shinsuke},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 49th Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics: Human Language Technologies: short papers-Volume 2},
  pages={529--533},
  year={2011},
  organization={Association for Computational Linguistics}
}
```

またdicomopapersというクラスファイルを以下からダウンロードしました。
https://dicomo.org/submission/

同ディレクトリ内にあるファイルはこの3つのみです。

コンパイル環境はCloud LaTeXです。

エラー内容は以下です。

```
main.bbl
line 5
! Undefined control sequence.
 \newblock

https://texwiki.texjp.org/?TeX%20%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8#b38c87ce

main.bbl
line 5
! Emergency stop.
 \newblock

https://texwiki.texjp.org/?TeX%20%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8#s9ac5238

警告
下記の警告があります。このままでもPDFの出力は可能ですが、修正を検討してください。
dicomopapers.cls
LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `dicomopapers',
               but the document class provides `ipsj'.

main.tex
line 5
LaTeX Warning: Citation `pathfind' on page 2 undefined on input line 36.
 \newblock \newblock

https://texwiki.texjp.org/?LaTeX%20%E3%81%AE%E8%AD%A6%E5%91%8A%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8#rf8e41bb
```

`\bibitem`による代用も考えましたが、こちらも同じエラーが出力されます。
`\cite`を消した場合にはPDFは出力されます。
エラーメッセージや「bibtex latex undefined」などで検索しましたが、原因が分かりません。

解決方法が分かる方がいらしたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「LaTeX newblock」というキーワードで Google 検索をすると「ある学会テンプレートを利用してエラーが発生」という類似事例がたくさんヒットしますね．

エラー箇所のうち，注目すべき箇所は以下の部分です．

```
line 5
! Undefined control sequence.
 \newblock
```

英語を読むと「`\newblock` というコマンドが未定義 (Undefined)」と言っていることがわかります．なので `\newblock` 命令を適当に定義してやればいいということになります．

この命令は，LaTeX の標準文書クラスである article.cls で次のように定義されています（最新版では584行目）：

```
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
```

ここで `@` を含む命令は内部用の命令で LaTeX 文書には直接書くことができないので `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother` で挟むことにより `@` を使える状態にする必要があります．

したがって，以下の内容をプリアンブル（`\documentclass` と `\begin{document}` の間の部分のことです）のどこかに記述すればエラーが解消するはずです．

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\makeatother
```

Comment: ご指摘の内容を所定の場所に追加したところ、問題なくpdfが出力されるのが確認できました。ありがとうございます。